# Rust TcpListener, статически слинкованный с MUSL отправляет неожиданный RST если запущен в Docker контейнере

Tags: docker, tcp, rust

Я пишу приложение на Rust, основанное на [Building a Single-Threaded Web Server](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html).
Запуск сервера происходит так:

```rust
// --
let listener = TcpListener::bind(&self.url).unwrap();
// URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
println!("Server started on {}", &self.url);
for stream in listener.incoming() {
    let stream = stream.unwrap();
    println!("Got connection");
    handle_connection(stream);
}
// --
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    println!("Reading request");
    let mut buffer = [0; 512];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    let contents = r#" <SOME HTML> "#;
    let response = format!("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n{}", contents);
    println!("Writing response");
    stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
// --
```

Я хочу деплоить это на мой удаленный сервер с помощью Docker. Но я не хочу чтобы мой образ занимал много места, поэтому как основу для образа я использую alpine:

```
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

COPY target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/<filename> .
COPY Config.toml .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["<filename>"]
```

Для того чтобы использовать alpine, перед этми мне приходится собирать файл с помощью rust-musl-builder:

```bsh
sudo docker run --rm -it -v `pwd`:/home/rust/src ekidd/rust-musl-builder
```

После этого я собираю и запускаю Docker образ:

```bsh
sudo docker build --no-cache -t <tag> -f <dockerfile from above> <directory>
sudo docker run --rm -dit --name <name> -p "8080:8080" <tag>
```

После этого, если я пытаюсь открыть http://127.0.0.1:8080/ в браузере, соединение обрывается:
[image: обрыв соединения]

При этом если я запущу `netcat -l -p 8080` внутри образа (вместо `<filename>` запущу `sh`, в нем запущу `netcat -l -p 8080`), при попытке открыть в браузере http://127.0.0.1:8080/ в netcat появляется код http запроса и я могу написать на него ответ вручную (например, `HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND ...`), ответ до браузера доходит.

При этом если я запущу `<filename>` локально, при открытии http://127.0.0.1:8080/ все прекрасно работает:
[image: все работает]

При этом если посмотреть что выводит `<filename>`, запущенный в контейнере, видно, что он пишет только `Server started on http://127.0.0.1:8080`, но никогда не пишет `Got connection`.

**Вопрос: что происходит, почему обрывается соединение, если я запускаю программу в Docker, но при этом локально все работает?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44099800/5247488)

Вам следует запускать приложение с URL `0.0.0.0:8080`, вместо `127.0.0.1:8080`

2) В браузере, открывайте не `127.0.0.1:8080`, а `<IP контейнера>:8080`

IP контейнера можно найти так:

- узнать название контейнера: `docker ps`
- узнать его IP: `docker inspect <название контейнера> | grep IPAddress`

Если хотите c браузера заходить по `127.0.0.1:8080`, то при запуске контейнера указывайте этот IP

`docker run --rm -dit --name <name> -p "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" <tag>`